# Issue with primary key when try persist entity in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring project, with uses Hibernate to handle all operations of access to database, I let the system create the tables in the database, and insert in them some default values.

One example of entity class, used as base for the creation of the tables, is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="permission")
public class Permissao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

My problem is that when I try insert a row via Java code in a table where already have inserted values, I am getting a message saying the primary key already exists.

My guess it's this happen because the somehow the counter from Hibernate isn't updated with the counter from database, but I don't understand enough about how this stuff work for be sure.

Anyone can tell what's happening and how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

That's where I insert this entity in the database:

```
public boolean cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String nome_grupo = request.getParameter("nome");
    String[] permissoes = request.getParameterValues("permissoes[]");

    if(nome_grupo == null || permissoes == null)
        return false;

    System.out.println("criando grupo");
    GrupoPermissao grupo = new GrupoPermissao();
    grupo.setNome(nome_grupo);

    System.out.println("adicionando permissoes");
    List<Permissao> lista = new ArrayList<Permissao>();
    for(int i=0; i<permissoes.length; i++)
        lista.add(permissao.findById(Integer.valueOf(permissoes[i]).intValue()));
    grupo.setPermissao(lista);

    System.out.println("salvando no banco de dados");
    boolean result = grupo_permissao.persist(grupo);
    System.out.println("id_grupo = "+grupo.getId());
    return result;
}
```

that's the entity GrupoPermissao, used above:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class GrupoPermissao {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="role_permissions", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_role")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_permission")})
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Permissao> permissao = new ArrayList<Permissao>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Permissao> getPermissao() {
        return permissao;
    }

    public void setPermissao(List<Permissao> permissao) {
        this.permissao = permissao;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solve this issue. The problem was the file used to populate the database was using INSERT with the indication of the primary key. I remove this reference to let the hibernate handle this, and now all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It posible that you insert id attribute when you create the object Permissao. It is not neccesary.

Comment: I update my question to include the  code where I do the insertion. I don't insert the id atribute in any place, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be that you declare the id as a primitive instead of a wrapper.

So instead of:

```
private int id;
```

You should have:

```
private Integer id;
```

When you create the group with:

```
GrupoPermissao grupo = new GrupoPermissao();
```

The id is 0, which is different from NULL.

So two requests calling this method will try to set the Group with id 0, so you have a clash.

Only when the id is NULL the AUTO generation strategy will let the database set the id instead.

And Hibernate doesn't store any id counters with the AUTO strategy, it delegates this responsibility to the database instead.

Comment: I update my code to change my Id as Integer, but still have the same problem (by the way, the entity isn't being initialized with 0, but with the last number in a sequence of numbers - in the moment the last number is 9 - , which match the number of elements I insert through the program, beacause that I think the Hibernate had your own counter).

Comment: One more thing, you call persist on GrupoPermissao but that doesn't have any cascade to private List<Permissao> permissao.